# how to create master detail combobox in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, combobox, oledb

I Have a excel sheet `test.xlsx`, two sheets within

Sheet name : `Product1` has following data :

```
ID  ParentID    Title
1   0           P1_1
2   0           P1_2
```

Sheet name : `Product2` has following data :

```
ID  ParentID    Title
1   1           P2_1
2   1           P2_2
3   1           P2_3
4   1           P2_4
5   2           P2_5
6   2           P2_6
```

calling both sheets in WindowsFormsApplication in asp net ( C# ) as :

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\test.xlsx" + @";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;ImportMixedTypes=Text;TypeGuessRows=0""";

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////

OleDbCommand command1 = new OleDbCommand
(
"SELECT ID ,ParentID ,Title " +
" FROM [Product1$]", conn
);
DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
OleDbDataAdapter adaptor1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(command1);
adaptor1.Fill(ds1);
Product1.DataSource = ds1.Tables[0];
Product1.ValueMember = "ID";
Product1.DisplayMember = "Title";

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////

OleDbCommand command2 = new OleDbCommand
(
"SELECT ID  ,ParentID ,Title " +
" FROM [Product2$] " , conn
);
DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
OleDbDataAdapter adaptor2 = new OleDbDataAdapter(command2);
adaptor2.Fill(ds2);
Product2.DataSource = ds2.Tables[0];
Product2.ValueMember = "ID";
Product2.DisplayMember = "Title";
```

i need to know how to create master-detail ( parent - child ) relation in both combo-box so that when first combo box value change , 2nd combo-box value too reflect changed by ParentID field ..

Comment: Look into the ASP.net Ajax control tool kit: http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.com/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx

Comment: i am beginner. just need simple windows forms solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by firing an event when an item is selected from combobox1 by selecting the current selected value. Based on selected value get the data from sheet2 and fill the second combobox.

```
<asp:ListBox ID="Product1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Product1_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:ListBox>
```

**CS Code**

```
int Id = 0;
int.TryParse(Product1.SelectedValue, out Id);
```

Now based on this id get data from sheet2 like this

```
OleDbCommand command2 = new OleDbCommand
(
"SELECT ID  ,ParentID ,Title " +
"FROM [Product2$] Where ParentId=@parentID" , conn
);
command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parentID", Id);
```

And rest of code for biniding will be same.

Comment: It is worth noting this will post back to the server every time `Product1` is changed.

Comment: Yes i know but as getting data from excel and binding it to combobox is done by c# code so this is just one solution.